# how to create new line between dateformat

Tags: java, android

i m creating date format like this :

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf =new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d, EEE, h:mm a");
```

i need a new line between date, month and time something like this

```
thus ,sep 6
4:25pm
```

so i made the following changes :

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf =new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d, EEE,"+"\n"+" h:mm a");
```

it did not give me anything just it created it in one line like this :

```
thus ,sep 6 4:25pm
```

so i took format object like this

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf =new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d, EEE,");
SimpleDateFormat sdf1 =new SimpleDateFormat(" h:mm a");
```

and did  this :

```
sdf.format(calendar.getTime())+"\n"+sdf1.format(calendar.getTime())
```

but it again gives the same result

```
thus ,sep 6 4:25pm
```

**calendar** is a Calendar object.Any help will be appreciated!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Android literally needs `\n` to appear in the string, not an actual newline character. So, you need to escape the backslash in your Java string, so something like this:

```
String output = "Thus ,Sep 6" + "\\n" + "4:25pm";
```

Comment: i need different time always cant use ur hard-coded value and also i tried using 2 back slashes

Comment: simple '\n' works.May be there was some problem with my JSON i am storing this into.My first way started working correctly after i took the same code inside another class.Thanks anyway..

Answer (score 10):

I see from one of your comments that your original solution actually works, but I had the same question when I came here, so let me add an answer to this question. (My formatting is a little different than yours.)

```
Date date = new Date(unixMilliseconds); 
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d, yyyy\nh:mma");
String formattedDate = sdf.format(date);
```

The `\n` in `MMM d, yyyy\nh:mma` works because neither the `\` nor the `n` are interpreted by `SimpleDateFormat` ([see documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)) and thus are passed on to the Java String. If they did have special meaning you could have used single quotes: `MMM d, yyyy'\n'h:mma` (which also works).

Comment: you are right may be. Thanks for your answer. I will try it if i will face any situation similarly in future. :)

Comment: Ok. The answer you marked as correct, though, seems to be wrong (the extra backslash is not needed before the n "\\n").

Answer (score 2):

Don't use \n, use :

```
System.getProperty("line.separator");
```

to get the line separator.

I found another source which tells that you can use `&#xA;` to have a carriage return.

Comment: i dont think it will work as System will not work android device or emulator.

Comment: @AndroidKiller I've looked at specific Android issues, and I found this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8693544/carriage-returns-line-breaks-with-n-in-strings-in-android

Comment: @AndroidKiller : added another possibility in Android.

Comment: @ LaGrandMere i think that can also be used in htmlo only.

Comment: @LaGrandMere The &#xA; worked for me. I've been searching for a solution for a while. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you're displaying to an HTML view, you will want to make sure you use an HTML line break `<br/>`, instead of `\n`.

Comment: i am displaying in android device.

Comment: What type of view are you sending your text to? Obviously, whatever it is, it doesn't support the `\n` character. You might want to try the "\n\r" as well.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure, that the `\n` disappears? At least your last try cannot have anything to do with the date format. Do you per chance create your output for a web page and should use `<br />` instread of `\n`?

Comment: Guys i am displaying in android device.

Comment: Ah, well then you have to make sure that TextView is set to multi-line!

Comment: For example see second answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6674578/multiline-textview-in-android

Comment: thanks i have already seen that post.not working for me. its cutting some text.:(

Comment: Could you post the code of your layout please? So I can see where you want the text to go?