# System.getProperty("line.separator") Vs "\n" for Android

Tags: java, android, linux, httpresponse

My query is whether `System.getProperty("line.separator")` and `"\n"` for Android network operations are same.
I mean to say. I will be getting line separated response from some server and so which is better to use `System.getProperty("line.separator")` or `"\n"`?

reffred [Carriage returns/line breaks with \n in strings in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8693544/carriage-returns-line-breaks-with-n-in-strings-in-android) but still not sure with network operations.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you get line separated responses use `BufferedReader.readLine()` to read each line and then use `System.getProperty("line.separator")` if you want to insert the newline back into the String.

Comment: I am currently doing it in the same way. but my concern is that ki will it `System.getProperty("line.separator")` give me same response across all the devices.

Comment: System.getProperty("line.separator") is meant to return the right line separator to you on that device. It will not return the same character across devices. Its purpose is lost if it returns the same character all the time.

Comment: you mean to say `BufferedReader.readLine()` internally uses `System.getProperty("line.separator")` to read lines from input stream.

Comment: Not exactly. It shouldn't matter what the line separator for your OS is when reading a response from the server. As long as a \r or \n is received, the framework should interpret that and read the line. From the docs - `A line is considered to be terminated by any one of a line feed ('\n'), a carriage return ('\r')`