# Using a line separator in android

Tags: java, android, string

In android does it make sense to use `System.getProperty(“line.separator);` instead of using `\n`?
Or is it considered 1 platform so `\n` is fine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android is based on a Linux kernel, so the line separator *should* be `\n`.  Therefore, using `\n` *should* be fine.  However, you are safer to use `System.getProperty("line.separator")` and let the JVM take care of the guesswork for you.  It isn't wrong to use `System.getProperty` but it might be wrong to use `\n`.

See [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8693544/carriage-returns-line-breaks-with-n-in-strings-in-android) for more information.

Comment: To be honest I am not in favor on doing things "just to be safe". Is there any reason to expect some corner case on this?

Comment: If an Android device be running on some weird flavor of Unix which uses a newline other than what you expect, you could get burned by hardcoding.

Comment: Which Unix flavour would come to mind? Also, since the OS comes from a single source (Google), how would any Android be based on a different Unix flavour?